# How to beautify this nested list with css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nested-lists

I made this drop-down menu with nested lists. But no matter how I adjust `height`, it is impossible to display every element in `.submenutwo`. Moreover, when hovering `.submenutwo` the user can no longer see the other options. Is there an easy way to fix this with css or very minimal javascript? Adjusting `height` to `min-height` does not work. I think `onclick` will be better than `hovering`.

```css
/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */

.navigation {
  min-width: 300px;
}
/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}
/* add hover behaviour */

.mainmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #C5C5C5;
}
/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
      display the submenu inside it.
      we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
    */

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
/*
      we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
      CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
    */

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}
/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}
/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
      we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
    */

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.submenutwo {
  display: none
}
.submenu:hover .submenutwo {
  display: initial;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">


    <li><a href="">Residential</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Interior</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#">Kitchen </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Bathroom </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Basement </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Bedroom </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Diner Room </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>



        <li><a href="">Exterior</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Doors and windows </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Garage </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Roofing </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#">  Insulation </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Masonry</a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="">Services</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>








    <li><a href="">Commercial</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Interior</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>



        <li><a href="">Exterior</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="">Services</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>




    <li><a href="">Industrial</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Interior</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>



        <li><a href="">Exterior</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> More option </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="">Services</a>
          <ul class="submenutwo">
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the css codes, may find what you want :)

```
/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */
.navigation {
    min-width: 300px;
}

/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */
.mainmenu, .submenu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */
.mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
}

/* add hover behaviour */
.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}


/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
  display the submenu inside it.
  we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
  */

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
    /*min-height: 200px;*/
    /*height:auto;*/
}

/*
we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
*/

.submenu a {
    background-color: #999;
}

/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */
.submenu a:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}

/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
*/
.submenu {
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    /*max-height: 0;*/
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}


.submenutwo {
    display: none
}

.submenu li:hover .submenutwo {
    display: block;
    /*min-height:300px;*/
    /*height:auto;*/

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed!